# Счетчик на Turbo Prolog

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите как правильно написать счетчик для определенных элементов в списке.
Нужно посчитать количество 1 в списке.
Пока у меня есть только правило на принадлежность элемента списку.

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-member(X,T).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принцип тот же, что и во вчерашней задаче.

Первый параметр - список, второй - результат

```
count([],0). % База рекурсии: в пустом списке единиц нет
count([1|T],Y1):-count(T,Y), Y1 is Y+1. % если голова списка единица, подсчитываем количество единиц в хвосте списка и увелививаем результат на единицу
count([_|T],Y):-count(T,Y). % любые другие элементы игнорируем, подсчитываем количество единиц в хвосте списка
```

Comment: спасибо,все получилось)

Answer (score 0):

Несколько вариантов.
Вот один из них:

```
database
  single count(integer)

clauses
    count(0).

    Считываем_элементы_списка(_,[]).
    Считываем_элементы_списка(Условие,[Элемент_списка|T]):-
        Проверка(Условие,Элемент_списка),
        Считываем_элементы_списка(Условие,T).

    Проверка(X,X):-count(N),N1=N+1,asserta(count(N1)),!.
    Проверка(_,_).

goal
    Считываем_элементы_списка(1,[1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1]),count(N),write('count 1:',N).
```